# Formula to remove text between two underscores in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

The value in cell A2 is "Blabla_Donkey_Rhino". I'd like a formula that removes the text between the two underscores and one of the underscores to return the value "Blabla_Rhino"

In Cell

```
A2

Blabla_Donkey_Rhino

Desired Output

Blabla_Rhino
```

Comment: The value in cell A2 is "Blabla_Donkey_Rhino".  I'd like a formula that removes the text between the two underscores and one of the underscores to return the value "Blabla_Rhino"

Comment: In case someone has a vba based solution to the problem

Comment: This isn't the best forum for questions like this, and there are dozens of ways to do this in excel depending on how often, how fast, and how you want to use it. Here is an ugly example: =CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,FIND("\_", A1)),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("\_",A1,FIND("\_",A1)+1)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "replace" vba alternative is not what you need, you may want to try just concatenating the beginning and ending parts of the text using something like this:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("_",A2))&RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("_",A2,FIND("_",A2)+1))
```

This follows your example, but it removes more than just the text between the two underscores, since it also removes the second underscore.

To remove just the text between the underscores, you would use something like this:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("_",A2))&RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("_",A2,FIND("_",A2)+1)+1)
```

Comment: Thank you @FocusWiz. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: That would be the easiest solution if you don't need the original values, but sometimes we don't have the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

VBA this simple UDF

```
Function firstAndThird(str as string) as string
    firstAndThird = split(str,"_")(0) & "_" & split(str,"_")(2)
End Function
```

Put code in a Module and call from sheet:

```
=firstAndThird(A2)
```

[image]

---

If you have Office 365 Excel then you can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("_",,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_",REPT(" ",99)),{1,198},99)))
```

Being an array formula confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]